# Time Based escalation in alertmanager

Tags: devops, monitoring, open-source, prometheus-alertmanager

Let's say I have an alert related to disk space, which is triggered at the following levels.
First at 85%(receiver for this is admin), then at 90%(receiver for this is super-admin) and finally at 95%(receiver for this ultra-admin).
Now the problem I want to tackle is, let's say the first alert was triggered and now the disk space is 88%. Now, whoever was the responsible person has received the alert but the alert hasn't been resolved for more than 40mins and the disk space remains at 88% only. The responsible person is getting the alerts but due to their unavailability they are not able to resolve this alert.
Now what I want to do is create an escalation policy in alertmanager such that let's say the first alert which was triggered hasn't been resolved by the admin in less than 30mins it should be escalated to the super admin and on a similar note if it hasn;t been resolved for more than 45 mins it should be escalated to ultra-admin.

My rule file looks like this

```
- alert: DiskUsage85
    expr: '(100 - (sum(node_filesystem_avail_bytes{instance="abc.xyz:9100"}  / node_filesystem_size_bytes{instance="abc.xyz:9100"}) BY (device,instance,mountpoint,stack) * 100)) > 85'
    for: 5m
    labels:
      maildest: admin
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      description: '{% raw %}{{reReplaceAll "(.*):(.*)" "${1}" $labels.instance}} - Disk {{$labels.device}} ({{$labels.mountpoint}}) has {{$value | printf "%.2f"}} (>80%) space usage{% endraw %}'
      summary: '{% raw %}WARN: {{ reReplaceAll "(.*):(.*)" "${1}" $labels.instance }} - Disk {{$labels.device }} ({{$labels.mountpoint}}) is {{$value | printf "%.2f"}}% full  {% endraw %}'
```

I have similar alerts for disk usage being 90% and 95% occupied

My alertmanager.yml is pretty vanilla( just adding the routes and receivers and I have similar receivers for super-admin and ultra-admin)

```
route:

  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 24h
  receiver: team-X-mails
  
  routes:
    - receiver: admin
      match:
        maildest: admin

    - receiver: super-admin
      match:
        maildest: super-admin

    - receiver: ultra-admin
      match:
        maildest: ultra-admin
        
receivers:
- name: 'team-X-mails'
  email_configs:
    - to: 'abc@gmail.com'
      send_resolved: true
      headers:
        subject: '[{{ .Status | toUpper }}{{if eq .Status "firing"}}:{{.Alerts.Firing|len}}{{end}}] {{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}'

- name: 'admin'
  email_configs:
    - to: 'admin@gmail.com'
      send_resolved: true
      headers:
        subject: '[{{ .Status | toUpper }}{{if eq .Status "firing"}}:{{.Alerts.Firing|len}}{{end}}] {{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Escalation of alerts is out of scope for alertmanager.

You could configure escalation in detail in PagerDuty or analogue.

Alternatively, you could create two more of the same alerts, but with `for: 30m` and `for: 45m` and corresponding receivers.

**Edit:** One more possible solution could be adding two more alert rules

```yaml
- name: escalation_policy
  rules:
  - alert: escalate_to_super_admin
    expr: ALERTS{escalation_level=""}
    for: 30m
    labels:
      escalation_level: super_admin
    annotations:
      summary: Alert hasn't been resolved by admin

  - alert: escalate_to_ultra_admin
    expr: ALERTS{escalation_level="super_admin"}
    for: 15m
    labels:
      escalation_level: ultra_admin
    annotations:
      summary: Alert hasn't been resolved by super admin
```

First rule creates additional alerts whenever non-escalated alert exists for 30 minutes.
Second one - whenever escalated alert exists for 15 minutes.

But this way you'll need do figure out how to pass original alertname label to escalated one.

Comment: Hey I want to stick to making changes in alertmanger.yml and I can't create more alerts with different for values as it will unnecessarily increase the size of my rules file.

Comment: @zimba, added I more possible way. It is sketchy, you'll need to check if it work how you want it. And I'm not sure there is trivial way to pass original alert name to new one.